# Collect files from several different directories and put them in one place

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a large amount of ebooks that are very disorganized. Some of them are alone in their own directories, some of them are corrupted, some of the directories are empty. How do I gather my ebooks from all these different directories, and put them all in one folder so I can read and reorganize them? I'd prefer using native GNU commands or a bash script.

Comment: Do they all have anything in common? Do they all have an .epub/.mobi extension? What information do you need to keep from the naming of the files at present, if any? When running the "file" command do you get output to tell you it is an ebook?

Comment: @Dayvo Most of them are .pdf, some of them are .epub. Once I get them all in one place, I'm going to ebook-convert the .epub files into .pdf files. I want to keep the whole filename of every file. "file" command outputs PDF Document 1.6 or EPUB Document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you at least have all of them in various subdirectories under a single parent folder. Something like `~/mybooks`. If so, you can do this:

```
find ~/mybooks -name '*.pdf' -or -name '*.epub' -exec mv -t ~/newdir {} +
```

That will find all files or directories whose name ends in `.pdf` or `.epub` in the directory `~/mybooks` and move them to the directory `~/newdir`. If you can have directories whose name ends in `.pdf` or `.epub`, add the `-type f` directive to get only files:

```
find ~/mybooks -type f -name '*.pdf' -or -name '*.epub' -exec mv -t ~/newdir {} +
```

Comment: Use `mv -t ~/newdir {} +` - should spawn fewer `mv`s.

Comment: @muru good point, I hadn't even added an `\;`, let alone a `+`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To move all the files with certain extensions in a directory tree (i.e. in a directory and its subdirectories recursively) to a single directory, in zsh:

```
mv -i source/**/*.(pdf|epub) destination/
```

The `destination` directory must already exist. You can omit the `source/` part if you want to collect files in the current directory and its subdirectories. If you want to move all the files regardless of their name, but not the directories:

```
mv -i source/**/*(.) destination/
```

In bash:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
mv -i source/**/*.@(pdf|epub) destination/
```

These commands may complain that the command line is too long if you have a lot of files. In this case, you can call `find` instead of using recursive globbing.

```
find source -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.epub' -exec mv -i -t destination/ {} +
find source -type f -exec mv -i -t destination/ {} +
```

If the existing directory structure carries some information, then instead of moving the files, you may find it more convenient to create [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) or [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

To make hard links, call `ln` instead of `mv -i`. With hard links, each file will be present in both places at once. If you remove either the original or the new file, the other one remains: the two locations of the file are on an equal footing. You can tell that a file has hard links because the number in the second column in the output of `ls -l` is greater than 1.

To make symbolic links, first change to the destination directory, and call `ln -s` using `.` (standing for the current directory) as the target. A symbolic link is a file which just says “look at this file over there instead”. If you remove the symbolic link, that doesn't affect the original file. If you move or remove the original file, the symbolic link becomes dangling (i.e. it's still there but no longer points to a file).

To remove empty directories under a directory, you can use

```
find /some/directory -depth -type d -empty -delete
```